# WebRequest Login

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to log on to a website and read a few source codes that include cookie_container, but can't get it to work!

My code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("www.addmesnaps.com/snapchat_online.php")
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
End Sub
```

Where shall I put the cookies, and how do I define the username and then click the button? It only asks to insert the username and then you're "Logged".

Comment: Learn html+js. Every site is a different case. There is no generic turn-key solution

Comment: and for this specific case? I know html, but don't see how I can fit it here...

Comment: Answer for this specific case includes all works and tricks. Sorry I am not willing to do your work.

Comment: @L.B how does this translate to the url?

$(function() {
    $('.snapuname').click(function() {
        selectText($(this).get(0));
    });
});[/code]

Answer (score 0):

It is still far from a real answer, but it is the much I can do with the informations you have given.

Login programmaticaly into a website is always a specific operation. All I can do is tell you how you can guess what you should do.

First study how you go to login page. It may be a redirection, or a simple display. It can give indication on what happens, but it does not really matter. But as soon as you have the login page, you should display it in HTML source code, search the login form in it and look for eventual javascript.

If no javascript is involved, you are lucky. You should easily find all the input fields (do not forget hidden ones) and simulate the submission. Normally, if you manage to setup a cookie container, you should get (after an eventual redirection) the expected page.

I there is some javascript, you can try to understand what the scripts do, but you will almost always need a network spy such as [wireshark] (http://www.wireshark.org/) to dump the requests and responses when you log in with a normal browser. Only with that you will be able to simulate the whole operation.

My conclusion  is that without a dump of the login page, and of the requests and response involved in logging, we can only give you general advices like this one.